# How to keep function variable in workspace to avoid load .mat file repeatedly in matlab?

Tags: matlab

```
function A(B,C)
  load d.mat
  my code 
end
```

Is there a way that I can use `d.mat` file without load/import it. Or is there a way that do not need to load/import `d.mat` file every time I run function `A`.

Comment: What is in `d.mat`, and why do you need it in your function?

Comment: I would call "load d.mat" inside the main script you are calling your function from and then pass the variables that are in d.mat into your function.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the variable/content of d.mat as an extra parameter to the function A.